# animation.start() or animation.startNow() does not start the animation immediately

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have a strange issue - from time to time the animation that should fade out my control (ImageButton) does not kick in immediately. I am using the fadeout animation to hide it and then in myListener on its end (onAnimationEnd) I put new resource as the image on the button.

Somewhere in my app code:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadeout); 
a.setAnimationListener(new myListener(location));
buttons[location].setAnimation(a);
a.startNow(); // regardless if its start() or startnNow() 
              // it will work in most of the cases but not 100% reliable
              // I actually can see in debug Log when its late, happens after few more clicks
```

Then in myListener.onAnimationEnd(Animation a):

```
buttons[location].setImageResource(R.drawable.standard_button);
```

Seems there is a rule that the every 4th or 5th animation does not start ...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

adding

```
buttons[location].invalidate();
```

after

```
a.startNow();
```

has fixed my issue.

Comment: If you accept your own answer, you'll get a badge, and this question will no longer show up as "not answered".

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
buttons[location].startAnimation(a);
```