# Splash screen does not transition to my main menu screen

Tags: android, android-activity, transition, splash-screen

I am currently working on an application that is supposed to have a transition from the splash screen to a main menu screen. I have done the coding but it doesnt seem to do that. Can anyone please spot out what is wrong with the code below?

**Splash screen Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = "GamePrefs";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    // fade in animation
    TextView logo1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
    Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    logo1.startAnimation(fade1);

    // custom animation
    Animation spining = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(spining);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
    for(int i=0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
        row.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    }

    startAnimations();

    // saving game preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("UserName", "JaneDoe");
    prefEditor.putInt("UserAge", 22);
    prefEditor.commit();
}

private void startAnimations() {
    // Transition from Splash screen to Main Menu screen
    Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
    fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,QuizMenuActivity.class));
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
        {
            //Nothing
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
        {
            //Nothing
        }
    });
}
```

**Main Menu Activity:**

```
public class QuizMenuActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    }
}
```

My layouts are done already. Any suggestions on what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the AnimationListener is never triggered? If you just want the Splash screen to display then leave.. how about just trying adding the following to your Splash activity's onCreate:

```
Thread timer = new Thread() {           
    public void run() {             
        try {                   
            sleep(5000); // Sets delay before splash appears        
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        } finally {
            Intent main = new Intent(Splash.this, MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(main);    
            finish();
        }       
   };   
   timer.start();
```

It sleeps for 5 seconds then goes to the MainMenu.

**Edit**

I think your AnimationListener is never being invoked, so try adding `fade2.startNow()` here:

```
private void startAnimations() {
    // Transition from Splash screen to Main Menu screen
    Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
    fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,QuizMenuActivity.class));
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
    {
        //Nothing
    }
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
    {
        //Nothing
    }
});
fade2.startNow();
}
```

For more information on how to use `Animation.startNow()` or `Animation.start()`:

[animation.start() or animation.startNow() does not start the animation immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604048/animation-start-or-animation-startnow-does-not-start-the-animation-immediate)

Comment: Hmmm, I could try that. I was just intending to get to the main menu after my animation on the splash screen finishes off.

Comment: When it was getting stuck on the Splash screen, was the Animation getting played?

Comment: Yes, the first animation gets played where it spins and comes into the front of the window... not the second one...

Comment: I think your AnimationListener isn't getting invoked. Read my comment and look at the link. Maybe it'll help you! =]

Comment: I'll surely give that a go and let you know what happens.